# Change of variables in Oppenheim example 2.5

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, change-of-variable

[image]

How do they do the change of variables from $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} \rightarrow \sum_{l=-n}^{\infty}$$

For the top, you can write $n = m-l = m + k$, so as $k \rightarrow -\infty$ then $n\rightarrow -\infty$, but in their case the upper bound is $\infty$. I also am not sure how to start on the bottom part of the summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Somewhat more elaborated we have
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n}2^k}&=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k=-m}^n2^k\\
> &=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k=-m}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-k}\tag{$2^k=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-k}$}\\
> &=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k=-n}^m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}\tag{$k\to -k$}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=-n}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

Without sum notation left-hand and right-hand sum from above are
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\cdots+2^{-1}+1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1}+2^n}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-n}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-(n-1)}+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}+1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1}+\cdots}
\end{align*}